# nginx conf express and assets returning 404

Tags: express, nginx

Have been at this all day and so far not getting to where I'd a liked to have been.

Running pretty much the latest version of everything as just building a new server to move off IIS/IISNode.

I have nginx installed and some conf going that serves only my main index file from a sub dir of /vra/www/. However it does not load any assets or sub-dir pages.

If I call the assets directly, using lowercase URL it returns 404 but uppercase URLs where needed work fine.

My conf example can be seen here: pastebin.com/a12TqP6w

[image: image1-ftpview]

Answer (score 0):

What all think in the webroot folder. I think it has only one directory html  your codes are put in the html directory there is no stuff in the mentioned directory     /var/www/dev.fishpal.com. change your configuration accordingly where is web content is placed.

Replace with this one.

```
root /var/www/dev.fishpal.com/html;
```

or put your codes and stuff in the following directory.

```
root /var/www/dev.fishpal.com;
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the 404 error for everything else other than the index.html page within dev.fishpal.com root folder

Comment: What kind of log access and error logs are produced by the Nginx. Put the log also.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to drop some extra things I had inside my conf file